# Can you use line breaks (<br/>) within a Microformat?

Tags: html, microformats

Is it valid to use a line break `<br/>` within a Microformat? Example:

```
<div class="vcard">
  <div class="fn">John Doe</div>
  <div class="adr">
    <div class="street-address">
      123 Orange Blossom Lane<br/>
      Calm Ocean, FL 33033
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use virtually any element you like with microformats, with a few exceptions. your markup example is perfectly valid, however i wouldn't put the br element there. and you could/should markup the city/state/zip with microformats as well. i threw together a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/jwcab/

Comment: Would it be safe to use the <address> tag to enclose the address? Example: <address class="adr">

Also, what if there are multiple addresses within the vcard?

Comment: if that address is in regards to contact info for the site, then yeah address. idk if you can mix hcard with address, but i certainly don't see why not. but if it's just a listing or something, it shouldn't be address.